# consulta un solo distinct con condicion

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

tengo una tabla con 4 columnas

```
id, descripcion_articulo, cantidad, modelo, marca
```

y esta consulta:

```
("select distinct descripcion_articulo from " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . "
where numeracion = '' order by descripcion_articulo ASC")
```

al generar esta consulta son justamente los articulos que deseo mostrar, esta perfecta, pero al agregar las otras columnas que faltan a la consulta:

```
("select distinct id, descripcion_articulo, cantidad, modelo, marca 
from " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . "
where numeracion = '' order by descripcion_articulo ASC")
```

muestra mas valores de los que deseo, de hecho repite valores de descripcion_articulo, que no deseo, solo deseo un solo valor unico de descripcion_articulo

necesito agregar los otros elementos `id`, `cantidad`, `modelo`, `marca` a la consulta realizada. como hacer la consulta.

**y agregar una columna adicional que suma todas las cantidades que contenga = descripcion_articulo**

Comment: Si quieres mostrar una sola fila para la descripción, qué aparecería en `modelo` y `marca`? Puede darse que modelos o marcas distintas tengan la misma descripción?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrupa por el campo que has utilizado para el distinct y utiliza este mismo campo para contar. La consulta funcionará mejor si este campo es un índice, he puesto el ejemplo con el campo descripción que usas al principio, dependiendo de la lógica que siga tu consulta y tus datos y el contenido puede ser mejor usar otro campo.

```
"SELECT COUNT(descripcion_articulo) AS total, 
  id, descripcion_articulo, cantidad, modelo, marca from " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . "
WHERE numeracion = '' 
GROUP BY descripcion_articulo
ORDER BY descripcion_articulo ASC"
```

Comment: tienes razon como agrego que sea distinto a 2 campos: modelo, marca

Comment: Puedes agrupar por varios campos